# How to use getElementById with a reactive var and Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, highcharts

In general doing a getElementById works pretty well like this :

```
console.log(document.getElementById('{{chart_id}}').setAttribute("id", "div_top2"));
```

But it returns me `null` and I don't really know why but I think it's becoming from the following lines:

```
<template name="chart">
   <div id="{{chart_id}}"></div>
 </template>
```

And later in the JS I do :

```
Template.currentData().chart_id
```

to get the div and place a HighChart here.

The thing I want to do is to rename the id (by the way I want to add a identifier so the final id would be something like `<div id ="{{chart_id}}+ a random number">`)

Then I could do this in my JavaScript:

```
Template.currentData().chart_id + theRandomNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have modified the HTML where I create the `<div>` and it looks like this :

```
  {{#each gimmeContainersToCreateChart}}
  {{> chart chart_id=this._id}}
  <!-- {{> chart chart_id="cpuChart"}}
  {{> chart chart_id="netChart"}}
  {{> chart chart_id="diskChart"}} -->
  {{/each}}
```

`gimmeContainersToCreateChart`returns a cursor with the running&&paused containers from the collection